# ".import" statement (for importing Qml type in JS) fails with syntax error

Tags: javascript, qt, import, qml

I registered a C++ type as a QML singleton object via `qmlRegisterSingletonType`. Then I tried importing this QML singleton into JS via:

```
.import FileIO 1.0 as FileIO
```

...and got a "Syntax error" message at runtime.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had some (non-comment) code before the `.import`. Moving the import before that code fixed it.