# Qt: Import Qml Module in imported Javascript resource

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I like to access a registered QObject from within an imported js resource (qml -> .js -> Module).
Access from QML works, but using ".import" as explained [in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html#importing-a-qml-module-from-a-javascript-resource) from within the js file does not. Some related issues raise the impression it may [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744471/import-statement-for-importing-qml-type-in-js-fails-with-syntax-error) ([another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793046/access-global-qt-object-in-javascript-file-qml)) or [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694314/how-to-include-qml-file-from-js-file).

Is it generally possible and how, only possible for certain modules, or not at all?

***Code with the annotated output of the console outputs:***

`main.cpp`

```
[...]
qmlRegisterSingletonInstance<MyModule>("org.example.MyModule", 1, 0, "MyModule", (new MyModule()));
[...]
```

`MyModule.hpp`

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
class MyModule : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum SOMETHING { AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE, FFF };
    Q_ENUM(SOMETHING)
};
```

`main.qml`

```
import org.example.MyModule 1.0
import "qrc:/something.js" as Something
[...]
console.log(MyModule, MyModule.DDD)// prints something like: "MyModule(0x....) 3"
[...]
Something.doit()
[...]
```

`something.js`

```
.import org.example.MyModule 1.0 as MyModule
[...]
console.log(MyModule, MyModule.DDD) // prints something like: "[object Object] undefined"
[...]
```

Comment: why you use `qmlRegisterSingletonInstance` ? your cpp class is not singleton .

Comment: what dose it mean `Import Qml Module in Javascript file` your title is wrong . you import one class from c++ in qml.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R The actual implementation is, it is actually just important that it is never instantiated twice.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R Edited the title, I try to import a module (c++ QObject) from a js file that is imported in qml (qml->js->module).
Importing it in the qml file itself works as expected, but in the imported js file it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from support: Apparently, you need to prefix the Module with the import namespace, i.e. `MyModule.MyModule.DDD` instead of `MyModule.DDD`:

```
.import org.example.MyModule 1.0 as MyModule
[...]
console.log(MyModule.MyModule, MyModule.MyModule.DDD)
[...]
```